# PHP Parse error with Symfony in bin/console file

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony 4.0. I am also using MAMP with PHP 7.2. After installing Symfony, I could not run the application. I stumbled into a PHP Parse error in the bin/console file. The parse error is at line 26 which reads:

```
$env = $input->getParameterOption(['--env', '-e'], $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev');
```

Any idea why that line produces a parse error?

Comment: Because you PHP version is 5.x, not 7.2. Check your MAMP settings. Especially php-cli version. An exact copy paste of the error message always helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe MAMP use your default PHP 7.2 version configured into it. 
But your console use the PHP version configured into your system path.

php -v in your console will give you the version used by your system. :)